# in regx, is it possible to accurately extract a json scalar value?

Tags: regex, json

wish to extract a scalar value from json.

- know JSON uses double quotes.
- know datatype of scalar: string, number, date, boolean.
- know scalar will be on first level, ie, not an attribute of an embedded object

  { "want": "string" }  => "string"

  { "want": 123 } => 123

  { "not": { "want": "wrong" }, "want": "right" } => "right

  { "nothing": 0 } => null / not found

do not know how to handle the opening/closing quotes, nor do I know how to handle embedded objects.

is this possible?

---

this is the best I have come up with so far:

```
// match `want` attribute
(?:"want"\s*:\s*)                                        

// string, number, boolean or null
(((?:")([^"]*)(?:"))|([-0-9][.eE0-9]*)|true|false|null)

// followed by comma or right bracket
(?:\s*(,|}))
```

it's good because it

- can be run in `postgres`
- grabs strings
- grabs numbers
- grabs boolean and null

it's bad because it

- does not ensure `want` is a first level attribute
- string value cannot have quote (") inside

Comment: In your use case, is it not possible to just parse the JSON and extract the value that way? Which language are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL in postgresql.  to fully parse the JSON quite expensive.

Comment: It is possible if you had one of the few regex flavours with recursion  or balanced groups support (PCRE and .NET for instance support that). Otherwise you'll not be able to properly parse data with arbitrary nested properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression will get you 50% of the way there:

```regex
(?<=:\s*)(".*?"(?<!\\")|\-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?)(?=\s*})
```

Or, when written as a multi-line regex:

```regex
(?x:
    (?<=:\s*)           # After : + space
    (

        ".*?"(?<!\\")   # String in double quotes

        |               # -or-

        \-?             # Optional leading -ve
        (0|[1-9]\d*)    # Number
        (\.\d+)?        # Optional fraction
        ([eE][+-]?\d+)? # Optional exponent

    )
    (?=\s*})            # space + }
)
```

This will not match your nested object example (`{ "not": { "want" ...`) or rather, it will match, but on the wrong thing. Also, your final example (`{ "nothing": 0 } => null / not found`) is difficult because `0` is a valid number. To work around the this problem, I would just check the result in procedural code and replace a result of `0` with `null`.

The nested objects problem is a whole different ball game though. It's getting into the realm of lexical analysis rather than simple tokenizing. At that point, you might as well just use a JSON library because you'd be writing a full JSON parser anyway. Fortunately, JSON is a simple enough grammar that it wouldn't be that expensive to use a third party library - certainly no more than doing it yourself.

I think the short answer is: from a simple `{ "name" : <value> }` object, yes, but from anything more complicated, no.

*For info on the JSON syntax, see http://www.json.org/.*

Comment: thanks, will test.  the `nothing: 0` part of the example was to say that that there was no `want` attribute so therefore returns not found - so no concern there.

Comment: Ahhh, you're trying to get the value of the `want` attribute? That makes things easier. Replace `(?<=:\s*)` with `(?<="want"\s*:\s*)`.

Comment: not getting there in `postgresql`.  here's the query: `# select substring('{"lgn_id":"1167681348698172","want":"1144591604514819","cmp_id":"4","login_ts":"2012-06-19 09:16:42","ip_addr":"127.0.0.1"}' from '(<=want\s*:\s*)(".*?"(?<!\\")|\-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?)(?=\s*})' );` => `ERROR:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid`.  according tohttp://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html it seems the `(<=` syntax is not supported, but even replacing it with `(?:` gets the same error.

Comment: Try this: `(?:want\s*:\s*)(("[^"]*")|\-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?))(?:\s*})`. I've removed some of the more dubious quantifiers. I have no idea if this is valid in PostgreSQL or not, and it's not going to be as accurate as the answer above as it will probably be too greedy.

Comment: have posted my results to bottom of question - thanks for insight